# Recursive quartile sorter in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, quartile

I am building a quartile sorter in Javascript. Codepen is below. Drag headers in the table to gray area above the table to see the table sort.
https://codepen.io/carbondesign/pen/MPPRPW?editors=0010

This code is working except for 2 problems:
1. I have written it long hand so as to break the problem down for myself
2. Sorting by a third column does not work.

To see #2, drag "area" into the sorter box(grey area above table) and the table sorts as expected (Russia is the largest country). Drag "population" into the sorter area and the table sorts as expected (China is the largest, highest population country). Drag "population growth rate" in to the sorter areas and it almost works but not quite. I get double values and the sort order should be as follows with Iraq being the largest, highest population country with the highest growth rate.

- Iraq 2.93
- Ethiopia 2.89
- Tanzania 2.79
- Angola 2.77
- Cameroon 2.59
- Madagascar 2.58
- Yemen 2.47
- Nigeria 2.45
- Congo 2.45
- Mozambique 2.45
- Afganistan 2.32
- Kenya 1.93
- Algeria 1.84
- Egypt 1.79
- Sudan 1.72
- India 1.22
- Pakistan 1.46
- Saudi Arabia 1.46
- Venezuela 1.39
- South Africa 1.33
- Turkey 1.26
- Iran 1.2
- Mexico 1.18
- Australia 1.07
- Columbia 1.04
- Burma 1.01
- Morrocco 1
- ...

The problematic code starts on line 154 (again, I wrote this out longhand on purpose):

```
    let thirdBuckets = [[],[],[],[]]
    secondBuckets.forEach( (secondbucket) => {
        secondbucket.forEach((currentVal) => {
            if(currentVal[sorters[i]] !== null){
                if(currentVal[sorters[i]] > columnSummary[sorters[i]].min && currentVal[sorters[i]] <= columnSummary[sorters[i]].first){
                    thirdBuckets[0].push(currentVal);
                }
                if(currentVal[sorters[i]] > columnSummary[sorters[i]].first && currentVal[sorters[i]] <= columnSummary[sorters[i]].mean){
                    thirdBuckets[1].push(currentVal);
                }
                if(currentVal[sorters[i]] > columnSummary[sorters[i]].mean && currentVal[sorters[i]] <= columnSummary[sorters[i]].third){
                    thirdBuckets[2].push(currentVal);
                }
                if(currentVal[sorters[i]] > columnSummary[sorters[i]].third && currentVal[sorters[i]] <= columnSummary[sorters[i]].max){
                    thirdBuckets[3].push(currentVal);
                }
            }else{
                nullBucket.push(currentVal);
            }
        });
        secondbucket.length = 0;
        thirdBuckets.forEach((thirdbucket) => {
            thirdbucket.forEach((currentVal) => {
                secondbucket.push(currentVal)
            })
        });

    })
    console.log(thirdBuckets);
    results.length = 0;
    secondBuckets.forEach((secondbucket) => {
        // regularSort(secondbucket, sorters[i])
        secondbucket.forEach((currentVal) => {
                results.push(currentVal)
        })
    })
}
```

All suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Given an array of sort methods:

```
[ (a, b) -> n ]
```

You can create a combined sort method by iterating over the methods and applying them until the first one returns either `-1` or `1`. You can do this using recursion, but it's easier in a simple loop:

```
// Using recursion
const chainSortRec = ([s = Done, ...sorters]) => 
  (a, b) => s === Done 
    ? 0 
    : s(a, b) || chainSortRec(sorters)(a, b);

// Using a regular loop
const chainSort = (sorters) => (a, b) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < sorters.length; i += 1) {
   const res = sorters[i](a, b);
   if (res) return res;
  }    
  return 0;
};
```

An example that sorts a set of arrays based on several sorters:

```js
const numSort = (a, b) => a > b ? -1 : a < b ? 1 : 0;

const sortBy0 = ([a  ], [b  ]) => numSort(a, b);
const sortBy1 = ([,a ], [,b ]) => numSort(a, b);
const sortBy2 = ([,,a], [,,b]) => numSort(a, b);

const Done = Symbol();

// Applies the first sort method, if any.
// If it returns 0, it recurses to the next.
// When out of sort methods, it returns 0.
const chainSortRec = ([s = Done, ...sorters]) => 
  (a, b) => s === Done 
    ? 0 
    : s(a, b) || chainSortRec(sorters)(a, b);

const data = [
  [2, 0, 0],
  [1, 0, 0],
  [1, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 0],
  [3, 0, 0],
];

console.log(
  data
    .sort(chainSortRec([sortBy0, sortBy1, sortBy2]))
    .map(xs => `[ ${xs} ]`)
    .join("\n")
);
```

This probably only partially answers your question, but I had a hard time going through all your lines of code and the mix with the UI code...

Anyway, here's a complete running console example with lots of comments that gives the results you've required:

```js
const data = [{"name":"Afghanistan","area":652230,"population":32564342,"populationGrowthRate":2.32},{"name":"Akrotiri","area":123,"population":null,"populationGrowthRate":null},{"name":"Albania","area":28748,"population":3029278,"populationGrowthRate":0.3},{"name":"Algeria","area":2381741,"population":39542166,"populationGrowthRate":1.84},{"name":"American Samoa","area":199,"population":54343,"populationGrowthRate":-0.3},{"name":"Andorra","area":468,"population":85580,"populationGrowthRate":0.12},{"name":"Angola","area":1246700,"population":19625353,"populationGrowthRate":2.77},{"name":"Anguilla","area":91,"population":16418,"populationGrowthRate":2.03},{"name":"Antarctica","area":null,"population":null,"populationGrowthRate":null},{"name":"Antigua and Barbuda","area":443,"population":92436,"populationGrowthRate":1.24},{"name":"Argentina","area":2780400,"population":43431886,"populationGrowthRate":0.93},{"name":"Armenia","area":29743,"population":3056382,"populationGrowthRate":-0.15},{"name":"Aruba","area":180,"population":112162,"populationGrowthRate":1.33},{"name":"Ashmore and Cartier Islands","area":5,"population":null,"populationGrowthRate":null},{"name":"Australia","area":7741220,"population":22751014,"populationGrowthRate":1.07},{"name":"Austria","area":83871,"population":8665550,"populationGrowthRate":0.55},{"name":"Azerbaijan","area":86600,"population":9780780,"populationGrowthRate":0.96},{"name":"Bahamas The","area":13880,"population":324597,"populationGrowthRate":0.84},{"name":"Bahrain","area":760,"population":1346613,"populationGrowthRate":2.41},{"name":"Bangladesh","area":143998,"population":168957745,"populationGrowthRate":1.6},{"name":"Barbados","area":430,"population":290604,"populationGrowthRate":0.31},{"name":"Belarus","area":207600,"population":9589689,"populationGrowthRate":-0.2},{"name":"Belgium","area":30528,"population":11323973,"populationGrowthRate":0.76},{"name":"Belize","area":22966,"population":347369,"populationGrowthRate":1.87},{"name":"Benin","area":112622,"population":10448647,"populationGrowthRate":2.78},{"name":"Bermuda","area":54,"population":70196,"populationGrowthRate":0.5},{"name":"Bhutan","area":38394,"population":741919,"populationGrowthRate":1.11},{"name":"Bolivia","area":1098581,"population":10800882,"populationGrowthRate":1.56},{"name":"Bosnia and Herzegovina","area":51197,"population":3867055,"populationGrowthRate":-0.13},{"name":"Botswana","area":581730,"population":2182719,"populationGrowthRate":1.21},{"name":"Bouvet Island","area":49,"population":null,"populationGrowthRate":null},{"name":"Brazil","area":8514877,"population":204259812,"populationGrowthRate":0.77},{"name":"British Indian Ocean Territory","area":54400,"population":null,"populationGrowthRate":null},{"name":"British Virgin Islands","area":151,"population":33454,"populationGrowthRate":2.32},{"name":"Brunei","area":5765,"population":429646,"populationGrowthRate":1.62},{"name":"Bulgaria","area":110879,"population":7186893,"populationGrowthRate":-0.58},{"name":"Burkina Faso","area":274200,"population":18931686,"populationGrowthRate":3.03},{"name":"Burma","area":676578,"population":56320206,"populationGrowthRate":1.01},{"name":"Burundi","area":27830,"population":10742276,"populationGrowthRate":3.27},{"name":"Cabo Verde","area":4033,"population":545993,"populationGrowthRate":1.36},{"name":"Cambodia","area":181035,"population":15708756,"populationGrowthRate":1.58},{"name":"Cameroon","area":475440,"population":23739218,"populationGrowthRate":2.59},{"name":"Canada","area":9984670,"population":35099836,"populationGrowthRate":0.75},{"name":"Cayman Islands","area":264,"population":56092,"populationGrowthRate":2.1},{"name":"Central African Republic","area":622984,"population":5391539,"populationGrowthRate":2.13},{"name":"Chad","area":1284000,"population":11631456,"populationGrowthRate":1.89},{"name":"Chile","area":756102,"population":17508260,"populationGrowthRate":0.82},{"name":"China","area":9596960,"population":1367485388,"populationGrowthRate":0.45},{"name":"Christmas Island","area":135,"population":1530,"populationGrowthRate":1.11},{"name":"Clipperton Island","area":6,"population":null,"populationGrowthRate":null},{"name":"Cocos (Keeling) Islands","area":14,"population":596,"populationGrowthRate":0},{"name":"Colombia","area":1138910,"population":46736728,"populationGrowthRate":1.04},{"name":"Comoros","area":2235,"population":780971,"populationGrowthRate":1.77},{"name":"Congo Democratic Republic of the","area":2344858,"population":79375136,"populationGrowthRate":2.45},{"name":"Congo Republic of the","area":342000,"population":4755097,"populationGrowthRate":2},{"name":"Cook Islands","area":236,"population":9838,"populationGrowthRate":-2.95},{"name":"Coral Sea Islands","area":3,"population":null,"populationGrowthRate":null},{"name":"Costa Rica","area":51100,"population":4814144,"populationGrowthRate":1.22},{"name":"Cote d'Ivoire","area":322463,"population":23295302,"populationGrowthRate":1.91},{"name":"Croatia","area":56594,"population":4464844,"populationGrowthRate":-0.13},{"name":"Cuba","area":110860,"population":11031433,"populationGrowthRate":-0.15},{"name":"Curacao","area":444,"population":146836,"populationGrowthRate":null},{"name":"Cyprus","area":9251,"population":1189197,"populationGrowthRate":1.43},{"name":"Czech Republic","area":78867,"population":10644842,"populationGrowthRate":0.16},{"name":"Ecuador","area":283561,"population":15868396,"populationGrowthRate":1.35},{"name":"Egypt","area":1001450,"population":88487396,"populationGrowthRate":1.79},{"name":"El Salvador","area":21041,"population":6141350,"populationGrowthRate":0.25},{"name":"Equatorial Guinea","area":28051,"population":740743,"populationGrowthRate":2.51},{"name":"Eritrea","area":117600,"population":6527689,"populationGrowthRate":2.25},{"name":"Estonia","area":45228,"population":1265420,"populationGrowthRate":-0.55},{"name":"Ethiopia","area":1104300,"population":99465819,"populationGrowthRate":2.89},{"name":"European Union","area":null,"population":513949445,"populationGrowthRate":null},{"name":"Falkland Islands (Islas Malvinas)","area":12173,"population":3361,"populationGrowthRate":0.01},{"name":"Faroe Islands","area":1393,"population":50196,"populationGrowthRate":0.51},{"name":"Fiji","area":18274,"population":909389,"populationGrowthRate":0.67},{"name":"Finland","area":338145,"population":5476922,"populationGrowthRate":0.4},{"name":"France","area":643801,"population":66553766,"populationGrowthRate":0.43},{"name":"French Polynesia","area":4167,"population":282703,"populationGrowthRate":0.94},{"name":"French Southern and Antarctic Lands","area":55,"population":null,"populationGrowthRate":null},{"name":"Gabon","area":267667,"population":1705336,"populationGrowthRate":1.93},{"name":"Gambia The","area":11295,"population":1967709,"populationGrowthRate":2.16},{"name":"Gaza Strip","area":360,"population":1869055,"populationGrowthRate":2.81},{"name":"Georgia","area":69700,"population":4931226,"populationGrowthRate":-0.08},{"name":"Germany","area":357022,"population":80854408,"populationGrowthRate":-0.17},{"name":"Ghana","area":238533,"population":26327649,"populationGrowthRate":2.18},{"name":"Gibraltar","area":7,"population":29258,"populationGrowthRate":0.24},{"name":"Greece","area":131957,"population":10775643,"populationGrowthRate":-0.01},{"name":"Greenland","area":2166086,"population":57733,"populationGrowthRate":0},{"name":"Grenada","area":344,"population":110694,"populationGrowthRate":0.48},{"name":"Guam","area":544,"population":161785,"populationGrowthRate":0.54},{"name":"Guatemala","area":108889,"population":14918999,"populationGrowthRate":1.81},{"name":"Guernsey","area":78,"population":66080,"populationGrowthRate":0.34},{"name":"Guinea","area":245857,"population":11780162,"populationGrowthRate":2.63},{"name":"Guinea-Bissau","area":36125,"population":1726170,"populationGrowthRate":1.91},{"name":"Guyana","area":214969,"population":735222,"populationGrowthRate":0.02},{"name":"Haiti","area":27750,"population":10110019,"populationGrowthRate":1.17},{"name":"Heard Island and McDonald Islands","area":412,"population":null,"populationGrowthRate":null},{"name":"Holy See (Vatican City)","area":0,"population":842,"populationGrowthRate":0},{"name":"Honduras","area":112090,"population":8746673,"populationGrowthRate":1.68},{"name":"Hong Kong","area":1108,"population":7141106,"populationGrowthRate":0.38},{"name":"Howland Island","area":2,"population":null,"populationGrowthRate":null},{"name":"Hungary","area":93028,"population":9897541,"populationGrowthRate":-0.22},{"name":"Iceland","area":103000,"population":331918,"populationGrowthRate":1.21},{"name":"India","area":3287263,"population":1251695584,"populationGrowthRate":1.22},{"name":"Indonesia","area":1904569,"population":255993674,"populationGrowthRate":0.92},{"name":"Iran","area":1648195,"population":81824270,"populationGrowthRate":1.2},{"name":"Iraq","area":438317,"population":37056169,"populationGrowthRate":2.93},{"name":"Ireland","area":70273,"population":4892305,"populationGrowthRate":1.25},{"name":"Isle of Man","area":572,"population":87545,"populationGrowthRate":0.76},{"name":"Israel","area":20770,"population":8049314,"populationGrowthRate":1.56},{"name":"Italy","area":301340,"population":61855120,"populationGrowthRate":0.27},{"name":"Jamaica","area":10991,"population":2950210,"populationGrowthRate":0.68},{"name":"Jan Mayen","area":377,"population":null,"populationGrowthRate":null},{"name":"Japan","area":377915,"population":126919659,"populationGrowthRate":-0.16},{"name":"Jarvis Island","area":5,"population":null,"populationGrowthRate":null},{"name":"Jersey","area":116,"population":97294,"populationGrowthRate":0.8},{"name":"Johnston Atoll","area":3,"population":null,"populationGrowthRate":null},{"name":"Jordan","area":89342,"population":8117564,"populationGrowthRate":0.83},{"name":"Kazakhstan","area":2724900,"population":18157122,"populationGrowthRate":1.14},{"name":"Kenya","area":580367,"population":45925301,"populationGrowthRate":1.93},{"name":"Kingman Reef","area":1,"population":null,"populationGrowthRate":null},{"name":"Kiribati","area":811,"population":105711,"populationGrowthRate":1.15},{"name":"Korea North","area":120538,"population":24983205,"populationGrowthRate":0.53},{"name":"Korea South","area":99720,"population":49115196,"populationGrowthRate":0.14},{"name":"Kosovo","area":10887,"population":1870981,"populationGrowthRate":null},{"name":"Kuwait","area":17818,"population":2788534,"populationGrowthRate":1.62},{"name":"Kyrgyzstan","area":199951,"population":5664939,"populationGrowthRate":1.11},{"name":"Laos","area":236800,"population":6911544,"populationGrowthRate":1.55},{"name":"Latvia","area":64589,"population":1986705,"populationGrowthRate":-1.06},{"name":"Lebanon","area":10400,"population":6184701,"populationGrowthRate":0.86},{"name":"Lesotho","area":30355,"population":1947701,"populationGrowthRate":0.32},{"name":"Liberia","area":111369,"population":4195666,"populationGrowthRate":2.47},{"name":"Libya","area":1759540,"population":6411776,"populationGrowthRate":2.23},{"name":"Liechtenstein","area":160,"population":37624,"populationGrowthRate":0.84},{"name":"Lithuania","area":65300,"population":2884433,"populationGrowthRate":-1.04},{"name":"Luxembourg","area":2586,"population":570252,"populationGrowthRate":2.13},{"name":"Macau","area":28,"population":592731,"populationGrowthRate":0.8},{"name":"Macedonia","area":25713,"population":2096015,"populationGrowthRate":0.2},{"name":"Madagascar","area":587041,"population":23812681,"populationGrowthRate":2.58},{"name":"Malawi","area":118484,"population":17964697,"populationGrowthRate":3.31},{"name":"Malaysia","area":329847,"population":30513848,"populationGrowthRate":1.44},{"name":"Maldives","area":298,"population":393253,"populationGrowthRate":-0.08},{"name":"Mali","area":1240192,"population":16955536,"populationGrowthRate":2.98},{"name":"Malta","area":316,"population":413965,"populationGrowthRate":0.31},{"name":"Marshall Islands","area":181,"population":72191,"populationGrowthRate":1.66},{"name":"Mauritania","area":1030700,"population":3596702,"populationGrowthRate":2.23},{"name":"Mauritius","area":2040,"population":1339827,"populationGrowthRate":0.64},{"name":"Mexico","area":1964375,"population":121736809,"populationGrowthRate":1.18},{"name":"Micronesia Federated States of","area":702,"population":105216,"populationGrowthRate":-0.46},{"name":"Midway Islands","area":6,"population":null,"populationGrowthRate":null},{"name":"Moldova","area":33851,"population":3546847,"populationGrowthRate":-1.02},{"name":"Monaco","area":2,"population":30535,"populationGrowthRate":0.12},{"name":"Mongolia","area":1564116,"population":2992908,"populationGrowthRate":1.31},{"name":"Montenegro","area":13812,"population":647073,"populationGrowthRate":-0.42},{"name":"Montserrat","area":102,"population":5241,"populationGrowthRate":0.5},{"name":"Morocco","area":446550,"population":33322699,"populationGrowthRate":1},{"name":"Mozambique","area":799380,"population":25303113,"populationGrowthRate":2.45},{"name":"Namibia","area":824292,"population":2212307,"populationGrowthRate":0.59},{"name":"Nauru","area":21,"population":9540,"populationGrowthRate":0.55},{"name":"Navassa Island","area":5,"population":null,"populationGrowthRate":null},{"name":"Nepal","area":147181,"population":31551305,"populationGrowthRate":1.79},{"name":"Netherlands","area":41543,"population":16947904,"populationGrowthRate":0.41},{"name":"New Caledonia","area":18575,"population":271615,"populationGrowthRate":1.38},{"name":"New Zealand","area":267710,"population":4438393,"populationGrowthRate":0.82},{"name":"Nicaragua","area":130370,"population":5907881,"populationGrowthRate":1},{"name":"Niger","area":1267000,"population":18045729,"populationGrowthRate":3.25},{"name":"Nigeria","area":923768,"population":181562056,"populationGrowthRate":2.45},{"name":"Niue","area":260,"population":1190,"populationGrowthRate":-0.03},{"name":"Norfolk Island","area":36,"population":2210,"populationGrowthRate":0.01},{"name":"Northern Mariana Islands","area":464,"population":52344,"populationGrowthRate":2.18},{"name":"Norway","area":323802,"population":5207689,"populationGrowthRate":1.13},{"name":"Oman","area":309500,"population":3286936,"populationGrowthRate":2.06},{"name":"Pakistan","area":796095,"population":199085847,"populationGrowthRate":1.46},{"name":"Palau","area":459,"population":21265,"populationGrowthRate":0.38},{"name":"Palmyra Atoll","area":12,"population":null,"populationGrowthRate":null},{"name":"Panama","area":75420,"population":3657024,"populationGrowthRate":1.32},{"name":"Papua New Guinea","area":462840,"population":6672429,"populationGrowthRate":1.78},{"name":"Paracel Islands","area":null,"population":null,"populationGrowthRate":null},{"name":"Paraguay","area":406752,"population":6783272,"populationGrowthRate":1.16},{"name":"Peru","area":1285216,"population":30444999,"populationGrowthRate":0.97},{"name":"Philippines","area":300000,"population":100998376,"populationGrowthRate":1.61},{"name":"Pitcairn Islands","area":47,"population":48,"populationGrowthRate":0},{"name":"Poland","area":312685,"population":38562189,"populationGrowthRate":-0.09},{"name":"Portugal","area":92090,"population":10825309,"populationGrowthRate":0.09},{"name":"Puerto Rico","area":13790,"population":3598357,"populationGrowthRate":-0.6},{"name":"Qatar","area":11586,"population":2194817,"populationGrowthRate":3.07},{"name":"Romania","area":238391,"population":21666350,"populationGrowthRate":-0.3},{"name":"Russia","area":17098242,"population":142423773,"populationGrowthRate":-0.04},{"name":"Rwanda","area":26338,"population":12661733,"populationGrowthRate":2.56},{"name":"Saint Barthelemy","area":null,"population":7237,"populationGrowthRate":null},{"name":"Saint Helena Ascension and Tristan da Cunha","area":308,"population":7795,"populationGrowthRate":0.24},{"name":"Saint Kitts and Nevis","area":261,"population":51936,"populationGrowthRate":0.76},{"name":"Saint Lucia","area":616,"population":163922,"populationGrowthRate":0.34},{"name":"Saint Martin","area":54,"population":31754,"populationGrowthRate":null},{"name":"Saint Pierre and Miquelon","area":242,"population":5657,"populationGrowthRate":-1.08},{"name":"Saint Vincent and the Grenadines","area":389,"population":102627,"populationGrowthRate":-0.28},{"name":"Samoa","area":2831,"population":197773,"populationGrowthRate":0.58},{"name":"San Marino","area":61,"population":33020,"populationGrowthRate":0.82},{"name":"Sao Tome and Principe","area":964,"population":194006,"populationGrowthRate":1.84},{"name":"Saudi Arabia","area":2149690,"population":27752316,"populationGrowthRate":1.46},{"name":"Senegal","area":196722,"population":13975834,"populationGrowthRate":2.45},{"name":"Serbia","area":77474,"population":7176794,"populationGrowthRate":-0.46},{"name":"Seychelles","area":455,"population":92430,"populationGrowthRate":0.83},{"name":"Sierra Leone","area":71740,"population":5879098,"populationGrowthRate":2.35},{"name":"Singapore","area":697,"population":5674472,"populationGrowthRate":1.89},{"name":"Sint Maarten","area":34,"population":39689,"populationGrowthRate":1.51},{"name":"Slovakia","area":49035,"population":5445027,"populationGrowthRate":0.02},{"name":"Slovenia","area":20273,"population":1983412,"populationGrowthRate":-0.26},{"name":"Solomon Islands","area":28896,"population":622469,"populationGrowthRate":2.02},{"name":"Somalia","area":637657,"population":10616380,"populationGrowthRate":1.83},{"name":"South Africa","area":1219090,"population":53675563,"populationGrowthRate":1.33},{"name":"South Georgia and South Sandwich Islands","area":3903,"population":null,"populationGrowthRate":null},{"name":"South Sudan","area":644329,"population":12042910,"populationGrowthRate":4.02},{"name":"Spain","area":505370,"population":48146134,"populationGrowthRate":0.89},{"name":"Spratly Islands","area":5,"population":null,"populationGrowthRate":null},{"name":"Sri Lanka","area":65610,"population":22053488,"populationGrowthRate":0.84},{"name":"Sudan","area":1861484,"population":36108853,"populationGrowthRate":1.72},{"name":"Suriname","area":163820,"population":579633,"populationGrowthRate":1.08},{"name":"Svalbard","area":62045,"population":1872,"populationGrowthRate":-0.03},{"name":"Swaziland","area":17364,"population":1435613,"populationGrowthRate":1.11},{"name":"Sweden","area":450295,"population":9801616,"populationGrowthRate":0.8},{"name":"Switzerland","area":41277,"population":8121830,"populationGrowthRate":0.71},{"name":"Syria","area":185180,"population":17064854,"populationGrowthRate":-0.16},{"name":"Taiwan","area":35980,"population":23415126,"populationGrowthRate":0.23},{"name":"Tajikistan","area":143100,"population":8191958,"populationGrowthRate":1.71},{"name":"Tanzania","area":947300,"population":51045882,"populationGrowthRate":2.79},{"name":"Thailand","area":513120,"population":67976405,"populationGrowthRate":0.34},{"name":"Timor-Leste","area":14874,"population":1231116,"populationGrowthRate":2.42},{"name":"Togo","area":56785,"population":7552318,"populationGrowthRate":2.69},{"name":"Trinidad and Tobago","area":5128,"population":1222363,"populationGrowthRate":-0.13},{"name":"Tunisia","area":163610,"population":11037225,"populationGrowthRate":0.89},{"name":"Turkey","area":783562,"population":79414269,"populationGrowthRate":1.26},{"name":"Turkmenistan","area":488100,"population":5231422,"populationGrowthRate":1.14},{"name":"Turks and Caicos Islands","area":948,"population":50280,"populationGrowthRate":2.3},{"name":"Tuvalu","area":26,"population":10869,"populationGrowthRate":0.82},{"name":"Uganda","area":241038,"population":37101745,"populationGrowthRate":3.24},{"name":"Ukraine","area":603550,"population":44429471,"populationGrowthRate":-0.6},{"name":"United Arab Emirates","area":83600,"population":5779760,"populationGrowthRate":2.58},{"name":"United Kingdom","area":243610,"population":64088222,"populationGrowthRate":0.54},{"name":"United States","area":9826675,"population":321368864,"populationGrowthRate":0.78},{"name":"United States Pacific Island Wildlife Refuges","area":22,"population":null,"populationGrowthRate":null},{"name":"Uruguay","area":176215,"population":3341893,"populationGrowthRate":0.27},{"name":"Uzbekistan","area":447400,"population":29199942,"populationGrowthRate":0.93},{"name":"Vanuatu","area":12189,"population":272264,"populationGrowthRate":1.95},{"name":"Venezuela","area":912050,"population":29275460,"populationGrowthRate":1.39},{"name":"Vietnam","area":331210,"population":94348835,"populationGrowthRate":0.97},{"name":"Virgin Islands","area":1910,"population":103574,"populationGrowthRate":-0.59},{"name":"Wake Island","area":7,"population":null,"populationGrowthRate":null},{"name":"Wallis and Futuna","area":142,"population":15613,"populationGrowthRate":0.33},{"name":"West Bank","area":5860,"population":2785366,"populationGrowthRate":1.95},{"name":"Western Sahara","area":266000,"population":570866,"populationGrowthRate":2.82},{"name":"Yemen","area":527968,"population":26737317,"populationGrowthRate":2.47},{"name":"Zambia","area":752618,"population":15066266,"populationGrowthRate":2.88},{"name":"Zimbabwe","area":390757,"population":14229541,"populationGrowthRate":2.21}];


// Logic helpers

// Returns the value at a point in a sorted array. E.g. p = 0.5 -> median
const valueAtPoint = (xs, p) => xs[Math.floor(xs.length * p)];

// Gets the index of an element's quarter in an array
const getQuarter = (xs, x) =>
  x === null                  ? null :
  x <= valueAtPoint(xs, 0.75) ? 0 :
  x <= valueAtPoint(xs, 0.50) ? 1 :
  x <= valueAtPoint(xs, 0.25) ? 2 :
                                3 ;

// Sort numbers largest first, null last
const numericNullLastSorter = (a, b) => 
  a === null ?  1 :
  b === null ? -1 :
  a < b      ?  1 :
  a > b      ? -1 :
                0 ;

// Decorates a sort function to first unwrap property values
const propSorter = (k, f) => (a, b) => f(a[k], b[k]);

// A recursive sort-chainer that keeps on recursing
// until it's either out of sorters, or a sorter has returned
// -1 or 1
const chainSortRec = ([s, ...sorters]) => (a, b) => 
s === undefined ?
  0 :
  s(a, b) || chainSortRec(sorters)(a, b);

// The same sort-chain but implemented as a loop
const chainSort = (sorters) => (a, b) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < sorters.length; i += 1) {
   const res = sorters[i](a, b);
   if (res) return res;
  }    
  return 0;
};

// The main app logic
// props is an array of strings (keys) we want to sort by, in order
// xs is an array of objects that contain those keys
const sortByProps = (props, xs) => {
const og = Symbol();
const quarterProps = props.slice(0, -1)
const numericProp = props[props.length - 1];

// For every property that sortst by quarter,
// we'll need to sort all items to be able to 
// determine the quarter indexes.
const sorts = Object.assign(
  {},
  ...quarterProps.map(k => ({
    [k]: xs
          .map(x => x[k])
          .filter(x => x !== null)
          .sort(numericNullLastSorter)
  }))
);

// We need a place to link the original entries ot the
// values that determine their sort order
const qIndex = xs.map(x => Object.assign(
  // Store a reference to the original item
  { [og]: x },
  // Store the numeric value of the last prop
  { [numericProp]: x[numericProp] },
  // Store the quarter index of the other props
  ...quarterProps.map(k => ({
      [k]: getQuarter(sorts[k], x[k])
  }))
));

// This is our array of sort functions
// Each sort function sorts descending based on a single property
const sorters = props.map(k => propSorter(k, numericNullLastSorter));


return qIndex
  // We sort the index based on all sort methods
  .sort(chainSort(sorters))
  // We return the original objects, not the cached sort values
  .map(x => x[og]);
}



// To format our tests:
const topFiveString = props => sortByProps(props, data)
  .slice(0, 5)
  .map(x => x.name)
  .join(", ");

console.log(

`TOP 5s:
  by area: 
    ${topFiveString(["area"])}
  by area & population: 
    ${topFiveString(["area", "population"])}
  by area, population & growth rate: 
    ${topFiveString(["area", "population", "populationGrowthRate"])}`

);
```